# Expected time to absorption in Markov Chain

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

I am reading the textbook Introduction to Stochastic Processes with R
Book by Robert P. Dobrow, page 126.

For an absorbing Markov chain started in transient state $i$, let $a_i$ be the expected absorption time, the expected number of steps to reach some absorbing state.

**I don't understand the below:**

The number of transitions from $i$ to an absorbing state is simply the sum of the number of transitions from  $i$ to each of the transient states until eventual absorption. The expected number of steps from  $i$ to transient state  $j$ is $F_{ij}$. It follows that

$$a_i=\Sigma_{k \in T}F_{ik}$$,
where T is the set of transient states.

Can anyone help me explain the above?

Comment: It is simply a direct translation of the verbal statement into mathematical symbols !

Comment: @trueblueanil But I don't understand verbal statement.

Comment: If you want to count how many tosses of a die are needed to get  $6$, the first toss might be $2$, the next $5$, the third $2$ again, and so on and so forth until one toss finally gives $6$. So you need to add up the expected number of tosses back and forth until you reach $6$, with one toss representing one time unit.

Comment: The quantity $\ F_{ij}\ $ is *not* the "expected number of steps from  $\ i\ $ to transient state  $\ j\ $."  It's the *expected total number of visits* to state $\ j\ $ between any time the chain is in state $\ i\ $ and the time of absorbtion. Those are two completely different quantities.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I am totally confused now. The book is here, page 126: http://dl.nemoudar.com/Introduction-to-Stochastic-Processes-with-R.pdf

Comment: @Jackie My apologies. I read the two sentences preceding the equation $\ a_i=\sum_{i\in K}F_{ik}\ $ without noticing that the second was a verbatim copy of the one I quoted as $\ F_{ik}\ $ not being.  However, that second  sentence   must be interpreted in the light of the first:
\begin{align}
&\text{The number of transitions from state }\ i\  \text{to an absorbing state}\\
&j\ \text{is simply the sum of}\color{red}{\text{ the number of transitions from $\ i\ $ to}}\\
&\color{red}{\text{each of the transient states until eventual absorption.}}
\end{align}

Comment: You need to read the second sentence as being a synonymous paraphrase of the one coloured in red in the above quotation —something I would not take it to mean when quoted in isolation.